# i3 Windows Manager - assigning window to workspace

Tags: terminal, i3, workspaces

How can I configure [i3 window manager](http://i3wm.org) to open new program (window) started in terminal on a specific workspace?

Answer (score 12):

This is what you have to put in your **~/.i3/config** file:

For example you want **Emacs** always opened up in work-space **4**.

```
assign [class="Emacs"]   4
```

How do you get the **class** info?

Run `xprop` and click on the window you want to capture. For example while Emacs is running, using another terminal execute xprop and then click on the Emacs window. In the output you will find :

> WM_CLASS(STRING) = "emacs", "Emacs"

The first string is the **instance** and the second one is the **class**.

*Finally restart i3 (**$mod+Shift+r** ) for the changes to take place.*

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's answered in i3 User Guide: [4.16. Automatically putting clients on specific workspaces](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#assign_workspace). You can match windows on many criteria - explained in detail [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_criteria).

For example the following config will always open Firefox on workspace 2:

```
assign [class="Firefox"] 2
```

As per second doc I linked in `class` selectors you can use regular expressions, so you can say that everything that's not your terminal will open on specific workspace.

Answer (score 0):

On startup, you use

```
assign [class="X-terminal-emulator"] 1'
assign [class="Firefox"] 10'
assign [class="Thunderbird"] 9'
assign [title="cmus v2.9.0"] 8'
```

You can also do that from the command line, notice that the syntax is different:

```
i3-msg '[class="X-terminal-emulator"]  move to workspace 1'
i3-msg '[class="Firefox"]     move to workspace 10'
i3-msg '[class="Thunderbird"] move to workspace 9'
i3-msg '[title="cmus v2.9.0"] move to workspace 8'
```